# joomla add html to menu link title

Tags: class, joomla, menu, tags, href

Hopefully a simple one...

I want to add the following inside a Joomla (v2.5.4) menu link along with the link text:

```
<i class="icon-book"></i>
```

Like this:

```
<li>
 <a href="page-name.html"><i class="icon-book"></i> Library</a>
</li>
```

I have tried putting the above tag inside the menu title as html, but joomla won't hold/save it and strips it out.

Any help/ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You mean : {<li><a href="page-name.html"><i class="icon-book">Library</i></a></li>} ??? So you want to make it italic with some style ?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla won't allow any tag's in the menu title, even HTML encoded (i.e. & lt; etc). To do it the way you're wanting to you would have to use a third-party menu system that support it - there are lots around that do, you can have a look at [Menu Systems](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems) section of the [Joomla! Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org).

Otherwise, in Joomla! you can use the parameters in "Link type Options" panel.

In this case you can assign a class to the  `<a>` tag by putting `aCSSClass` in the "Link CSS Style" parameter. Then your `<a>` tag will render as `<a class="aCSSClass" href=...`

Then you can define the class in your templates CSS file and do what you want.